# Is that possible for Keras to implement the consistency loss for unsupervised data augmentation(UDA)?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am currently reading a paper: [UNSUPERVISED DATA AUGMENTATION FOR CONSISTENCY TRAINING](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12848.pdf) by Google and CMU last year. I think the method of using data augmentation for unlabeled data and adding the consistency loss for the robustness is interesting. For example, in the figure, it shows that the final loss is consists of the ordinary supervised loss and the unsupervised loss part. The authors did augmentations fo the unlabeled data, and if the model gives different predictions for the unlabeled data and its augmentation, then the difference (KL distance in the paper) would be the consistency loss for the model.
[image]

I would like to try this method on some of my previous models, which were written in Keras. And I only found some implementation of this method in Tensorflow and PyTorch. I wonder if it is possible to implement this structure also in Keras? Since I only have experiences for building the supervised learning part in Keras, could anyone give some ideas of how to do the unsupervised consistency loss part in Keras?

Thanks!!